# How to properly quote something in a Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, quotes

What is the proper way to quote a variable in a batch file?

I've found that something like `"%~dp0"` doesn't work because it turns out to be something like `"C:\Windows\"`, which in turn gets interpreted as having an escaped quote at the end.

Oh and of course there's always problems with embedded quotes -- any way to escape those too?

Comment: +1: That's a good question ain't it? =D  I tried playing around with a mix of ^, & and | around the variable with different quotes, back quotes etc. (even though some of the variations are silly and I knew it wouldn't work), but can't seem to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a bit the different quote/escape problems here.
In batch itself there are different rules for quotes and escapes than for `reg`.

In batch a caret escapes the next character, but only outside of quotes (there is only one exception for escaping an exclamation mark inside of quotes).

`reg.exe` uses the `\` to escape the next character, **EDIT:** but it seems that it only escapes a quote character.
To embedd a single quote it's easier to use two quotes.
Only a backslash at the end of the content is a problem, as it escapes the last quote.

```
Reg Add HKCU\Temp /d "One""two\\" /t REG_SZ
```

Adds `One"two\`

Comment: Wait, `reg` **unescapes** the strings I give it? I didn't see this documented anywhere -- are you sure?

Comment: Nearly, I tested it and it works with `"C:\Hello""world\\"`, but it seems to be a bit more complex, see my edit

Comment: My guess is that it follows [these rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391.aspx), though I could be wrong. I don't believe it has anything to do with Reg.

Comment: But even if `reg.exe` uses the `CommandLineToArgvW` function, it's `reg` who do the unescape, and it doesn't explain why "" results into a single quote

Comment: No. `cmd.exe` doesn't use this sort of escaping. A simple test shows the result `echo "One""two\\"` results in the output of `"One""two\\"`

Comment: Echo is a special command -- it's the worst thing you could possibly test with! (That doesn't mean you're wrong, though.)

Comment: But even `ECHO` doesn't affect the expansion of the rest, for an explanation of the expansion rules try a look at [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Answer (score -1):

Which variable are you trying to quote ? If you have defined the variables in the environment/system varaibles, then you can quote it as 
`%variable_name%`.
 For example if you need to quote the 'path' variable, then `%path%` is the right way

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass something with spaces into a variable use ` ( top left of the keyboard ), this should also deal with embedded quotes. If you're passing a variable with spaces into another batch use double quotes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to escape them at all.